# Как возвести в квадрат число с плавающей точкой , чтобы программа не выходила за пределы double, но и работала верно?

Tags: c++, c, математика, численные-методы, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

В этой программе вводим сначал n-количество чисел, которые будем вводить , а затем n чисел вводим. Суть в том , что при вводе чисел таких как 3.е165 программа выводит inf т.к. выходим за пределы double~e308. А преподаватель просит , чтобы программа работала без никаких проблем на таких значениях. Что делать ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define N 10000
double norm2(double a[],int n);
int main(void)
{
    double a[N]; int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    norm2(a,n);
    
    return 0;
}
double norm2(double a[],int n)
{
    int i=0; double sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%le",&a[i]);
        if(a[i]<0.0) a[i]=-a[i];
        sum+=exp(log(a[i])+log(a[i]));}
    printf("%le",sqrt(sum));
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Вам надо не возвести число в квадрат, чтоб не выходило за пределы, а потом еще и извлечь квадратный корень - а это уже существенно меняет дело... А вы про корень ничего не упоминаете! Замечу вскользь, что, например, `sqrt(a^2+b^2) == a*sqrt(1+(b/a)^2)`... Намека достаточно?

Comment: А как можно это сделать с числами с плавающей точкой ? Я не упоминал  корень , потому что хотел с квадратом полностью разобраться

Comment: Так, как я и написал... Понятно, что не пытаясь заменить `a^2` на `exp(log(abs(a))+log(abs(a)))`, а просто на `a*a`. А разобраться с квадратом - так неужели вы не понимаете, что с **квадратом** вы ничего не сделаете - потому что результат выходит за пределы типа! Это как если бы вы через пропасть в 3 метра шириной прыгали на метр - "я сначала хочу на метр научиться прыгать, а потом уж и на 3..." Или "я сначала в бассейн с вышки прыгать научусь, а уже потом напущу воду и буду учиться плавать..."

Comment: Вы действительно думаете a*a что то изменит ? Снова программа выводит inf

Comment: Вы читаете, что я пишу? Я вам даже формулу привел. Про **корень**. Ну, блин, в самом деле, ну что я, должен за вас все написать? Пережеванное - невкусно! Потренируйте свои зубы хоть немного!

Comment: Я все понимаю конечно

Comment: Тогда в чем вопрос?

Comment: А можно ли написать программу не перемножая числа с плавающей точкой ?Например при вводе 3.e165 и 4.е165 по вашей формуле все должно нормально выводить ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нате, сдайте и не мучьтесь. В конце концов, чем меньше нынешние студенты будут работать мозгами, тем выше будут зарплаты у тех, кто таки работает...

```
double norm2(double a[],int n)
{
    double sum = 0, maxa = fabs(a[0]);
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if (maxa < fabs(a[i])) maxa = fabs(a[i]);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        double x = a[i]/maxa;
        sum += x*x;
    }
    return sqrt(sum)*maxa;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    double * a = malloc(n*sizeof(double));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        scanf("%le",&a[i]);
    printf("%le\n",norm2(a,n));
}
```

Вот полный код - https://ideone.com/qFxpez - это чтоб не началось "у меня то или это не компилируется"...

Comment: Странный вы человек однако

Comment: `return sum*maxa;` выглядит подозрительно. Если функция считает норму, но нужно извлечь квадратный корень из `sum`. Если квадрат нормы, то нужно домножить на `maxa`. Хотя может здесь расчёт чего-то другого...

Comment: Да , я заметил . Мне надо просто корень извлечь и умножить на maxa

Comment: @wololo Да, описка. Спасибо! Да вы не стесняйтесь, в таких случаях подправляйте сразу ответ...